# MySQL Table Adding Double Value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table on mySQL console.

```
CREATE TABLE TRY (Essn int(10), Pno int(2), Hours DOUBLE(40,0));
```

When I try to add something to table:

```
INSERT INTO TRY ('123456789','1','32,5');
```

I got an error about syntax. I couldn't find the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: change `32,5` to `32.5`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I tried it too, I got the same error.

Comment: You are missing the `VALUES` keyword.

Comment: @eggyal Oh, now I realised it. I should take a break! Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of the quote, replace *32,5* with 32.5, and add `VALUES` keyword should work:

```
INSERT INTO TRY VALUES (123456789,1,32.5);
```

You might also want to change your double field definition for allowing more decimal numbers in `Hours` field:

```
CREATE TABLE TRY (Essn int(10), Pno int(2), Hours DOUBLE(40,2));
```

refer to MySQL's [approximate value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) section for more details

> “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total,
>   of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a
>   column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed.
>   MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert
>   999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) Erreur de syntaxe pres de '123456789,1,32.5)' a la ligne 1. I have no idea why its in French

Comment: @Dosher I updated the solution with `VALUES` keyword

Comment: Now I managed to add values to table but 32,5 value became 32 in table. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Dosher change your table definition to something like `Hours DOUBLE(40,2)` rather than leaving it as 0 as that integer stands for number of decimals

Comment: I think I need to delete that data first. DELETE FROM TRY WHERE .... I couldn't figure out after where part.

Comment: @Dosher You can just execute `DROP TABLE TRY` and then `CREATE TABLE TRY (Essn int(10), Pno int(2), Hours DOUBLE(40,2));`, I suppose you don't have many important rows in the table yet.

Comment: At first I thought about it but I want to know what should I do if I had important rows.

Comment: @Dosher `DELETE FROM TRY WHERE Essn=123456789`, then execute `ALTER TABLE TRY change Hours Hours DOUBLE(40,2);` , but I guess it might be fine to execute the alter command directly without deleting the row first.

Comment: But now I had another problem again. I did as you said but Hours value is 32.00 in table. It rounded it again.

Comment: @Dosher That should be the old data we inserted previously, try add another row with 32.5 and check what's in the table for the new row. Your schema is changed to `DOUBLE(40,2)` now, right?

Comment: I tried different values. Tried to add 7,5 but in table it is 7.00. I used describe try command and Type of Hours Field is double(40.2). I really don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Dosher You mean `7,5`, or `7.5`?

Comment: I wrote 7,5. Now I tried 7.5 and problem solved! Thank you so much again, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In your creation, you defined that you do not want any digits saved after the decimal point. DOUBLE(40,0) means you have 40 digits and 0 of them after the decimal point.

Also see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html for more information.

Comment: It should be fine, mysql will round up to the 0 decimal point when insert a value, for instance, 40.85 becomes 41 automatically

Comment: @ElMatze if I use DOUBLE(40,1) will I get result as 32.5?